# Installing XDebug in Docker

Tags: php, docker, installation, xdebug

I'm trying to install the XDebug in a Docker container, but I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php-xdebug
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get install php-xdebug -y

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

When I'm running the same command in my computer, the XDebug is getting installed without any error:

```
apt-get install php-xdebug
```

Where might the problem be?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following lines into my Docker file:

```
# "xdebug-2.9.0" for PHP<=7.4 — "xdebug" (3) for PHP>=8
ARG XDEBUG_VERSION="xdebug-2.9.0"

FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN yes | pecl install ${XDEBUG_VERSION} \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini


COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Hi, when I use this with https://localhost, the webserver does not respond. Do you have any hint, what I cold do?

Comment: @Bernhard, perhaps you forgot to bidn ports with -p when starting the container? Either way, you can start a new question with your full dockerfile and commands that you use :-).

Comment: @UrmLnm thanks for your reply. Manwhile it works, even if I do not know what makes it work. I wanted to build a testproject for IntelliJ - this worked. Then I tried with my real project and it worked as well. Mabe it was because of reboots, docker updates or whatever.

Comment: As of now we can shorten some of this to `RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`

Comment: In my case, this command helped `RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`

Comment: if you aren't using the apache image, you can find php extension directory with `$(find $(php-config --extension-dir) -name xdebug.so)`

Comment: What a pain still in 2022. Why can't the maintainers of the official PHP images ensure that stuff like PHP extensions install SMOOTHLY and without workarounds?

Comment: Default version changed and will fail with PHP 7.x. — For PHP 7.4 install `xdebug-2.9.0`, while for PHP 8.x install `xdebug` (will default to version 3.x)  [at least, as in 2023]

Answer (score 35):

try this:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Comment: Please note for PHP 5.x you have to explicitly specify version `pecl install xdebug-2.5.5` since newer versions of xdebug don't support 5.x any more

Answer (score 21):

As of PHP 7.4 you only need this

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

And add this line to enable remote debugging

```
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
```

Comment: i guess that host.docker.internal is mac only ... if you're on ubuntu you should use 172.17.0.1

Answer (score 9):

Since xdebug version 3 there are breaking changes in config names.

```
RUN pecl install xdebug; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

and for configuration:

```
        { \
            echo "xdebug.mode=debug"; \
            echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes"; \
            echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal"; \
            echo "xdebug.client_port=9000"; \
        } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
```

More info: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Be aware that another one of the breaking changes is that the default port has changed from 9000 to 9003, so if your IDE has not been updated and now (also) listens to 9003 that last echo line is necessary, but better update or change your IDE configuration.

Comment: Would you mind explaining where the "and for configuration" section belongs?

Comment: It's a bash script (for dockerfile) that automatically put proper php/xdebug configuration into docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini file.

Comment: @MikeiLL if you use a Dockerfile like me, you can put the xdebug config settings into it like this: `RUN echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/xdebug.ini ... `

Answer (score 5):

For PHP 7.3 I was able to install XDebug using the mlocati's [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer).

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions xdebug @composer
```

My `docker-compose.yml` contains the following which allows the special `host.docker.internal` name:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

My xdebug configuration file `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini` looks like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = "host.docker.internal"
xdebug.client_ip = "9003"
xdebug.idekey="VSCODE"
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```

More details are in a [Gist describing my PHP Debugging in Docker setup](https://gist.github.com/megahirt/e80086d1d029a7406e9eaec1fb1dcc9e).

Comment: `xdebug.client_ip`: you mean `xdebug.client_port` I hope?

Answer (score 0):

I was using `php8.0-alpine` in the dockerfile.
I was having an issue in installing `xdebug` in the container,
so I changed the image to `php8.0-alpine3.13` and works fine.
Seems like 3.14 was having some issue with xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that use of  `xdebug.remote_enable` and `xdebug.remote_host` is no longer correct as these options are renamed in xdebug v3 and now you should to use config names instead:

```
# For xdebug v3
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
```

Docs: