# how can I install zip extension in php:5.4-apache docker

Tags: php, linux, docker, libzip

## Problem

I want to setup a docker based development environment for a PHP application.
This environment shall mimic the production server.

This application wants to export an xlsx file and throws `Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/html/lib/xlsxwriter.class.php on line 95`

**Any attempt to install zip extension for PHP in my docker container fails**

## fist attempt

```
#chose the php version here
FROM php:5.4-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mysql zip

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907308/installing-xdebug-in-docker
# this is for php 7
#RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
#    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
#    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
#    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug-2.4.1 \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini


RUN usermod -u 431 www-data
```

I get `configure: error: zip support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located`

## second attempt

I have added

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-zlib-dir=/usr/src/php/ext/zip/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mysql zip
```

but got `configure: error: Can not find zlib headers under "/usr/src/php/ext/zip/"`

## third attempt

```
RUN apt-get install libzip /
  && pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && pecl install  zip
```

ends in

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure' failed
```

## other attempts

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip libzip2 \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

`W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.12.204 80]`

Comment: PHP 5.x is no longer supported!  Please upgrade to a current 7.2+ release

Comment: For the third attempt, try libzip => libzip-dev

Comment: @Eakethet I had tried this as well but with the same effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55361762/596285

Comment: @BMitch thanks a lot for that hint it helps me out of the 404

Comment: @GordonM I tried with 7.3 with the same effect

Comment: @Bernhard You should stick with a current version of PHP anyway, because old versions are no longer supported and therefore security vulnerabilities will not be fixed.  No version of PHP 5 is currently supported, nor is PHP 7.0

Answer (score 8):

With the help of @yosifkit I found the solution (https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/748#issuecomment-480449743)

just for reference: here are  my dockerfiles. I am sure they can be optimized, But they work for my project.

This is for php5.4: Even if php5.4 it is out of date, but I need it for maintenance and therefore I wanted to use docker to get a running environment.

```
FROM php:5.4-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list  # Now archived

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mysql

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug-2.4.1 \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN usermod -u 431 www-data

RUN set -eux; apt-get update; apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev; docker-php-ext-install zip
```

for php7.3

```
#chose the php version here
# FROM php:7.0-apache
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug-2.7.0 \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN usermod -u 431 www-data

RUN set -eux; apt-get update; apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev; docker-php-ext-install zip
```