# Editing php.ini to enable XDebug for Docker and Drupal

Tags: php, docker, drupal, xdebug, portainer

I am a real beginner with Docker & Portainer. I am trying to setup a local test environment using Docker for my Drupal 7 & 8 Sites. I've used the Stacks editor inside Portainer to define two containers for Drupal. I want to edit the php.ini file to enable XDebug so I can do some debugging for some custom PHP code via VSCode.

I cannot find a way (to find or) edit the php.ini for those Drupal boxes. I am placing the code I used for in the Stacks Editor below.

```
version: '2'

services:  
 
traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web-secured.address=:443
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock         
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
stg.company:
    image: drupal:7.36
    container_name: stg.company
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /Work/stg.company:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.company_org_nginx-http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.company_org_nginx-http.rule=Host(`dev.company.org`)
stg.portal.company:
    image: drupal:7.36
    container_name: stg.portal.company
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /Work/stg.portal.company:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.portal_company_org_nginx-http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.portal_company_org_nginx-http.rule=Host(`dev.portal.company.org`)
```

Comment: Have a look at [Installing XDebug in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907308/installing-xdebug-in-docker) and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you are having with your existing `php.ini`? Is XDebug enabled?

Comment: Hi @halfer, thank you for comming back. The only things I am running are the ones shown above. I did not install a XAMP (or something equivalent) on the box. As such, I cannot find when the php.ini is event located to go and edit it :-( . It is somewhere (i guess, but not sure where to find it), so I can edit it...

Comment: So your Dockerfile is [something like this](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/c9f287f02d7c12ec7c1f89e4ed43005f5e90a7ef/7/apache-buster/Dockerfile). I would guess you'd use `docker-php-ext-install xdebug` in your own Docker build. Are you familiar with how to do that?

Comment: To find you php.ini on the cli, looking in "php -i | grep ini" or go to phpinfo, which can be found by going to your Drupal status page and clicking on the php version.  You should be able to just drop an xdebug.ini in the PHP config directory the above commands which show you, rather than mess with the php.ini.